# Non-consumable in app purchases in iOS. Do I need a server?

Tags: ios, storekit, in-app-purchase

I'm implementing an iPad game and want to allow the player to buy an extra map.  Do I need to implement a server and store that purchase so that I can handle the user changing to a different device or does the StoreKit handle it automatically for different devices?  That is if the user purchases the extra map on device A using his username and then installs the game on a new device B with the same username do I need to do something special or will the StoreKit remember the purchase so that he won't be billed twice?

Comment: When using the same Apple ID account, He won't be billed twice, but he should "purchase" it again for free (if it's Non Consumable).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No server is really needed for this - make button for "restore purchases" and user will be able to get all his "extra maps" on every device.
[Nice framework to implement it](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit).

Comment: To add to that, see WWDC Sessions (#122 from 2009 and #510 from 2011) on In App Purchase. They both touch on using your own server as an option in the process, but don't elaborate. There is a reference to this being something that can help reduce piracy, b/c you get to verify previous payment receipts beyond just accepting them from Apple's servers.

Comment: If the user hasn't jailbroken their device, the addition of your own server doesn't really add to the process. The benefit of your own server is *if* the user has jailbroken their device and then runs a tool that lets them bypass the AppStore for in-app purchase. By having  your own server in the mix authenticating receipts, which the crackers aren't expending the time to code for, you have an added layer of protection to reduce piracy.